# c++ Overload operator in abstract class

Tags: c++, class, interface, casting

I have the folllowing interface:

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual A * operator+(const A &rhs) const = 0;
}
```

And the abstract class :

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B(int val)
    {
      this->val = val;
    }

    virtual A * operator+(const A &rhs) const
    {
      return (new B(this->val + rhs.val));
    }
    int val;
}
```

Moreover, I have this class :

```
class C
{
  public:
    void add();
  private:
    std::stack<A *> Astack;
}
```

**The operator+ prototype cannot be modified.**

My issue is that I fails to create the add function. I tried this:

```
void    C::add()
{
  B first = *dynamic_cast<B *>(this->Astack.top()); // Error here
  this->Astack.pop();
  B second = *dynamic_cast<B *>(this->Astack.top()); // And here
  this->Astack.pop();
  B * res = first + second;
  this->Astack.push(res);
}
```

But my compiler tells me :
error: cannot convert `B` to `A *` in initialization.
In fact, I fails to obtain to `B` to add them.

Comment: Don't implement operator overloading in that way. Note that your additions are leaked (Consider an expression like `a + b + c`, which generates two temporaries: It leaks at least one temporary)

Comment: I'm forced to do that, It's a school exercise

Comment: Ok, tell your teacher to not treat C++ as Java. Polymorphic operator overloading has no sense at all in this context. Just implement different overloads for different cases. C++ relies on duck typing for this kind of things: If there is an operator+ overload for types `T` and `U`, then `T` and `U` are considered addable. You don't provide an addition polymorphic interface and let classes implement that interface to be considered addable.

Comment: Is that for this reason that I've got a -1 ?

Comment: Yes, its mine. But don't be sad: Its really a downvote **for your teacher**. Please show him this thread.

Comment: What you could try is to implement this inherited behaviour (The addition in this case) as a mixin, as I suggested in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17125610/1609356

Comment: The advantage of that approach is that there is no pointers/ dynamic polymorphism (The operator returns just the right type), and there is no coupling (Its a mixin, isn't?)

Comment: Of curse if you wan't to adapt that to your problem, you should change the implementation of the CRTP-base operator+ to rely on the `add()` method of the derived class. If you wan't I could write an answer with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators cannot be virtual (well, technically they can, but it's a recipe for disaster, causing slicing, weird arithmetic expressions in client code and the unwarranted murder of cute baby seals).

Your `C::add` should look similar to this:

```
void C::add() // assuming implementation is supposed to sum instances and 
              // add replace the contents of Astack with the sum
{
    A* x = Astack.top();
    Astack.pop();
    while(!Astack.empty()) {
        A* y = Astack.top();
        Astack.pop();

        A* z = (*x) + (*y);
        delete x;
        delete y;

        x = z; // latest result will be in x on the next iteration
    }
    Astack.push(x);
}
```

Also, your teacher should learn about not abusing memory allocation, not abusing virtual functions, not imposing virtual operators and good and bad practices in C++ class interface design - including the correct function signatures for overloading arithmetic operators).

Answer (score 0):

`first` and `second` both are pointer variable and holding address. and you cant add two address.

`first + second` is not calling you operator overloading function, try by using `*first + *second`

Comment: In the OP example, first and second are Stack variables, so the operator call is correct.

Comment: @MatthiasBonora the question is modified after my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
B * res = first + second;  // Error here !
```

Here you try to assign a A* pointer (which is returned by operator+) to a B* pointer. You have to cast the result. Something like that:

```
B * res = dynamic_cast<B*>(first + second);
```

Edit: not that you should use operator overloading in this way. utnapistim gave a good answer about that.