# Operator overloading and inheritance (keeping the same type)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a bit of a problem with operator overloading and inheritance in C++.

Quick sketch:

```
class A {
public: 
    A operator+ (const A &b) const { ... }
};

class B : public A {
    ...
};
```

Now suppose I have two instances of `B`, `x` and `y`. If I add them I will get a thing of type `A`, however I want it to be of type `B`.

What is the best way of accomplishing this (aside from reimplementing them in class `B`) ? CRTP?

Comment: You might use a constructor in B converting A to B `B(const A&)`. However, if B holds additional information, overwrite the operator.

Comment: You have to reimplement it in B but you can call the base class's implementation by return A::operator+(b);

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ operator overloading with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122111/c-operator-overloading-with-inheritance)

Comment: What about the other properties of `B`?  Why is `B` related to `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `operator+` outside of the class as a template:

```
template<class type> type operator+(const type& left, const type& right)
{
    type toReturn;
    toReturn.value = left.value + right.value;
    return toReturn;
}

class A {
private:
    int value;

    template <class type> 
    friend type operator+<type>(const type& left, const type& right);
};

class B : public A {
};

int main()
{
    B test1, test2;

    B test3 = test1 + test2;
}
```

This approach has certain down-sides.  The compiler will aggressively try to instantiate the `operator+` template for types which you don't want to define `operator+`, so be aware of that.

Comment: Could I suggest some modification? * value must not be redeclared in class B as it is inherited from A, * make value private and declare the global operator + friend of A

Comment: I ended up using CRTP, since I didn't want to pollute my namespace. Still, thanks -- I'm going to accept this answer