# C++: Using parent class operator function to update inherited variables of a child class object

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, operator-overloading

To simplify my doubt, I have written some dummy code which highlights the same problem.

So, I have a class named Box which has an overload for + operator. Next, a class named Cube is declared which inherits from Box class. I wish to be able to use the + overload defined in Box class. This seems plausible to me as any Cube object is also a Box object and the inherited variables should be configurable from inherited functions. The current problem lies that + operator returns a Box object which can not be converted to a Cube object. But I am unable to use the information that *this is a Cube object.

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box {
   double length, breadth, height;

public:
   Box();
   Box(double l, double b, double h){
      length=l;breadth=b;height=h;
   }
   double getVolume() {
      return length * breadth * height;
   }
   // Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
   Box operator+(const Box& b) {
      Box box;
      box.length = this->length + b.length;
      box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
      box.height = this->height + b.height;
      return box;
   }
};

class Cube: public Box {
public:
   Cube();
   Cube(double size):Box(size,size,size){}
   Cube operator+(const Cube& b) {
        return (Box(*this)+b);   // this is wrong
   }
};

// Main function for the program
int main( ) {
   Cube C1(5),C2(10),C3; 
   C3=C1+C2;
   cout << "Volume of C3 : " << C3.getVolume() <<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I have read many answers on this topic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122111/c-operator-overloading-with-inheritance) is probably the closest to this question. But the accepted answer would convert the Cube object to Box object which is undesirable in later portions.

EDIT: The question was found to be unclear by many people of the community. (I am sorry. But this is my first question on stack). Please don't go by what is happening in the overloaded function. The idea is that I don't want to copy the contents of + operator in Box class to the + operator of Cube class. I need the + operator of Box class returning a Box object, and a + operator on Cube class which among other things, performs the Box + operation on inherited variables, and returns a Cube class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cube inherits the operator+ from Box. You don't need to implement it again in Cube.
But when removing the Cube operator+, you'll notice that `C3 = C1 + C2;` gives an error. C1 + C2 results in a Box-type, and you want to assign it to a Cube type. Her you should ask yourself a question: should C3 be a Cube type? If you add two cubes, will you get another cube? I don't think so. So C3 should be Box-type. Then the code works for me.

p.s.You also don't need the this->[member variable]. You already have access to the private member variables, as you define operator+ as a member function.

Edit: just to add working code

```
#include <iostream>

class Box
{
private:
    double length;
    double breadth; // ?? do you mean "width"?
    double height;

public:
    Box() {}
    Box(const double l, const double b, const double h)
        : length(l)
        , breadth(b)
        , height(h)
    {}

    // I don't know why the members are private? But you need access to check for a cube.
    double getLength() const { return length; }
    double getBreadth() const { return breadth; }
    double getHeight() const { return height; }

    double getVolume() const
    {
        return length * breadth * height;
    }

    // Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
    Box operator+(const Box& b)
    {
        return Box (
            length + b.length,
            breadth + b.breadth,
            height + b.height);
    }
};

class Cube : public Box
{
public:
    Cube(const double size = 0)
        :Box(size, size, size)
    {}

    Cube(const Box& b)
        : Cube(b.getLength())
    {
        if ((b.getLength() != b.getBreadth()) || (b.getLength() != b.getHeight()))
            throw std::invalid_argument("Box is not a Cube!");
    }
};

// Main function for the program
int main() {
    Cube C1(5), C2(10), C3;
    C3 = (C1 + C2);
    std::cout << "Volume of C3 : " << C3.getVolume() << std::endl;
    int temp;
    std::cin >> temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I could not come up with a good example to explain my requirement. Please read the EDIT append that I have added. I need C3 to be cube type.

Comment: Then you should append my answer with that of xaxxon, so implement a cube constructor that takes a box input. And implement logic that checks if the input box is a valid cube.

Comment: As you still haven't marked anything as 'best answer', I guess you're either still struggling (or an opportunist ;) ), so I added some code that works for me.

Comment: Yes. I am still struggling a bit. I see that you have overloaded the = operator. But converting box to cube via constructor looks more generalized to me. I will accept it as the answer once I am able to implement this into my code, as I would probably need further clarifications on this topic. (This code is just an analogy) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: And if you see the code carefully, you can prove that sum of two cubes will always be a cube ;)

Comment: Ok, so I changed the code again to suit you. It is not best practice to throw an exception from an object constructor, as this prevents the object destructor from being called.
If you want a more general answer, you should maybe rephase your question.
Although in your code, the sum of two cubes is another cube, in real life, stacking two cubes is not a cube. But that's just the real life analogy ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Cube constructor that takes a Box, then the code will work:

```
Cube(Box const &);
```

Since now the compiler can implicitly convert from a `Box` to a `Cube`.

live: https://godbolt.org/g/JMAuz2

Of course you'll need to put some logic into the new constructor to make sure the box is actually a cube - likely throwing an exception if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what problem you are facing as your question is quite unclear. But, I think this is what you want. Hope this helps

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box {
public:
double length, breadth, height;
Box(){}
Box(double l, double b, double h) {
    length = l; breadth = b; height = h;
}
double getVolume() {
    return length * breadth * height;
}
// Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
Box operator+(const Box& b) {
    Box box;
    box.length = this->length + b.length;
    box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
    box.height = this->height + b.height;
    return box;
}
};

class Cube : public Box {
public:
Cube(){}
Cube(double size) :Box(size, size, size) {}
Cube operator+(const Cube& b) {
    Box b1(this->length, this->breadth,this>height),b2(b.length,b.breadth,b.height),b3;
    Cube t(this->breadth);
    b3 = b1 + b2;
    t.length = b3.length;
    t.breadth = b3.breadth;
    t.height = b3.height;
    return (t);  
}
};

// Main function for the program
int main() {
  Cube C1(5), C2(10), C3;
  C3 = C1 + C2;
  cout << "Volume of C3 : " << C3.getVolume() << endl;
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Then your compiler let's you compile wrong code. This line is wrong `Box b1(this->length,this->breadth,this>height),b2(b.length,b.breadth,b.height),b3;` Notice the 3rd word "`this`". You have `this>height`, not `this->height`. You should do some research on compiler flags